# How to install Tomcat7 in Linux

Tags: amazon-ec2, tomcat7

Hi I have a amazon cloud and I'm trying to install TOMCAT7 I'm following few steps like

```
 sudo yum install tomcat7-webapps tomcat7-docs-webapp tomcat7-admin-webapps
 sudo service tomcat7 start  // to start the TOMCAT7 Server
```

but after starting the server I'm unable to see the default page of tomcat from URL

```
 http://localhost:8080
```

Can someone will guide me why it is so and how can i resolve it. or this is the the wrong me please suggest me something

```
 another thing which i want is that i wants to put my war file in webapp folder but i don't know since I'm new bee to Linus.
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

'Typically' tomcat gets installed at /usr/share/tomcat7/ on ec2, Put your app there. Hoping u r on ur machine, how can u access a public machine using "localhost"?

1. Verify in server.xml that tomcat is listening at 8080 -unless you
   have changed it, it should be
2. In security groups, for inbound add a rule to allow traffic at 8080, its disabled by default
3. On your dashboard, after selecting the instance, get the public IP
4. Use this IP to access your app (or just he default tomcat page)